# how can I show column numbers in eclipse (Juno) status bar

Tags: eclipse

In my older version of eclipse, I used to get the line number:column number at the status bar.

But when I upgraded to eclipse Juno, it is missing.
I am aware of the print margin settings but I want the column number to be displayed.

Is there a way out for enabling or displaying the line number : column number?

Comment: This should always be shown in the status line at the bottom when a text editor has focus.

Comment: You upgraded to juno? Juno was released in 2012.